# Raspberry Pi 3 PiCamera Still Frame Rate

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I'm working with a Raspberry Pi 3 that has a ribbon PiCamera.  My problem is that I cannot get the still (not video) frame rate to be workable.  In my application, the camera acts like a scanner using only a single row of each frame to watch things go by.  While the concept is fine, what's killing me is the frame rate which I cannot get above 30 FPS.

A perfect solution would be for someone out there taking the raspicam source, stripped it down and tuning it for speed, and bolting it up to OpenCV.  Has anyone done this?  Did it work?

The Ava Group in Spain (https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40) took an initial stab at this, but their still frame rate is also limited to 30 FPS.

Comment: (You may need to switch to a _line camera_.)

Comment: But what is a "line" camera?

Comment: The distinctive feature of a line camera is the use of a sensor with cells arranged in a _line_ rather than in a rectangle of any height to speak of. "Frame" rates typically about ten times that of "similar" rectangular sensors/cameras. (Would you believe something like fast video-modes of PiCamera discussed at [RaspberryPi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Camera+rate)?) `still frame rate` meaning you get to trigger capture, whereas video mode goes up to 90 fps?

Comment: Greybeard - I've been through all the discussion on Raspberry PI and I cannot find a word about a 90 FPS still rate.  What I did find in http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/50862/raspistill-speed/50874#50874 was: "If a time-lapse value of 0 is entered, the application will take pictures as fast as possible. Note there is an minimum enforced pause of 30ms between captures to ensure that exposure calculations can be made."

Comment: Also Greybeard - I've been unable to find any source of line cameras - would you have any ideas?

Comment: By searching for "line scan" rather than "line", I was able to locate items such as http://www.robotshop.com/en/parallax-linescan-imaging-sensor-daughterboard-tsl1401.html?gclid=CM_YyNLoitACFRYvgQoddsgH-w

Comment: I'd consider [this one](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=5290) more typical: thousands of cells in the line, external trigger rate well into the hundreds. (The sensors are pretty cheap, _if_ they don't need to be fast. But because they are long, the optics gets (much) larger than for, say, a half-inch 5:8 sensor. And low volume kills value/price.)

Comment: I don't believe you can get past 30FPS using stills on a Pi - the 90FPS is for video. With stills you have to send the whole image to disk - you're going to be limited by disk write speed on the SD card as well as the processing power of the camera. You could try writing to the RAM disk and lowering resolution to 640x480 but I don't think you'll get above 42FPS